# Manually adding confidence interval shading to multiplot line graph in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, confidence-interval, linegraph

I am trying to manually add shading of the confidence interval into a line graph with multiple types of vegetation over two different seasons. I used r2winBUGS to calculate my 95% confidence interval for each point, but now I am attempting to add those calculated confidence intervals to a plot.
 This is the graph that I want to add confidence interval to.

[image]

This is my data: lower is the lower bound and upper is the upper bound.

```
    Type       Season Period     Ticks Lower Upper
 11 Invasive      1      1 0.011256249 0.004 0.016
 12 Invasive      1      2 0.008556320 0.004 0.011
 13 Invasive      1      3 0.006569459 0.004 0.009
 14 Invasive      1      4 0.005106834 0.003 0.007
 15 Invasive      1      5 0.004036758 0.002 0.006
 16 Invasive      2      1 0.007419884 0.005 0.010
 17 Invasive      2      2 0.011886079 0.009 0.015
 18 Invasive      2      3 0.019135467 0.015 0.023
 19 Invasive      2      4 0.030961773 0.024 0.038
 20 Invasive      2      5 0.050353671 0.036 0.068
 21   native      1      1 0.009722436 0.002 0.008
 22   native      1      2 0.007394854 0.004 0.013
 23   native      1      3 0.005683424 0.007 0.020
 24   native      1      4 0.004424967 0.011 0.032
 25   native      1      5 0.003505384 0.017 0.053
 26   native      2      1 0.006407294 0.003 0.012
 27   native      2      2 0.010282212 0.003 0.009
 28   native      2      3 0.016583555 0.002 0.007
 29   native      2      4 0.026882597 0.002 0.005
 30   native      2      5 0.043801800 0.001 0.004

 ggplot(data = invci, aes(x = Period, y = Ticks)) -> i
 n <- i + geom_point(aes(color = factor(Type))) + facet_wrap(~invci$Season)
       + geom_line(aes(color = factor(Type))) + labs(colour = "Type")
```

I've been trying to use geom_ribbon:

```
 ci <- n + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Lower, ymax = Upper), alpha = .3, linetype=2)
```

But been getting something like this. 
[image]

Comment: You don't have a grouping variable in the `geom_ribbon` layer.  If you want different ribbon colors, you can add `fill = Type`.  Otherwise you can use `group = Type`.  However, your intervals don't encompass the estimate for some groups so things look a bit odd.

Comment: Also don't use dollar signs in `facet_wrap`.  Refer to the variable directly, `facet_wrap(~Season)`.